# Define type for createSelector from useQuery result

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I try to get the correct typings for the createSelector res parameter, but I can't seem to find the correct one from redux-js as there is no example or explanation regarding this usage in TypeScript, only in JS.

```js
const selectFacts = React.useMemo(() => {
    return createSelector(
        (res) => res.data,
        (data) => (data ? pick(data, facts_keys) : undefined)
    );
}, []);

const { facts } = useGetProfileQuery(user?.email ?? skipToken, {
    selectFromResult: (result) => ({
        ...result,
        facts: selectFacts(result),
    }),
});
```

As can be seen here: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#selecting-values-from-results

No example showing how this should be done in TypeScript, has anyone else already faced this?

I eventually ended doing type assertion so i won't get stuck on a type definition error.. But this is not ideal at all so any alternatives would be welcomed.

Comment: I want to confirm that You want to pass argument in selector right?

Comment: @ParthM.Dave yes i do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "full type" of something like that. Just specify what you need.

Your selector only accesses `data`, and on another point in your app you defined that endpoint so you have an interface for that flying around already.

So you can just do

```
const selectFacts = React.useMemo(() => { 
  return createSelector(
    (res: { data: YourDataInterfaceOrType }) => res.data, 
    (data) => (data ? pick(data, facts_keys) : undefined) 
  ); 
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fit the types for selector the following way (adapted my code to your example):

```
return createSelector(
        [(res: UseQueryStateResult<any, any>) => res.data],
        (data : Profile) => data ? pick(data, facts_keys) : undefined
)
```

However, I'm not actually sure that it's correct.